# Sublime Text Plugin Dev - Open a file, Focus folder in sidbar

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to expand my Sublime Text 3 Plugin, it currently watches for the creation of a .php file with a prefix of lp_ and creates a folder of the same name for css and images.

I am trying to find a way to focus the sidebar on the assets folder after creation and also open the style.css file as well. The goal is to be able to create a plugin that allows for rapid creation of landing pages.

Any Sublime Text / Python Gurus no how I could possibly focus on sidebar / open file?

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os
# We extend event listener
class lp_folder_create(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # This method is called every time a file is saved (not only the first time is saved)
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        variables = view.window().extract_variables()
        fileBaseName = variables['file_base_name'] # File name without extension
        file_path = variables['file_path']

        if fileBaseName.startswith('lp_'): #checks for php prefix

            if file_path.endswith('/themes/folder'): # Only watches certain folder
                path = file_path + '/lp/' + fileBaseName
                imagepath = path + '/images/'
                os.mkdir(path) # Creates folder
                #TRYING TO FOCUS SIDEBAR ON THIS FOLDER
                os.mkdir(imagepath)
                open(path + "/style.css", 'w') # Creates style.css
                #TRYING TO OPEN THIS FILE IN SUBLIME AFTER CREATION
                os.system('open "%s"' % (path + "/")) #Opens in finder for placement of image assets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file where you know the full path is pretty straight-forward. Just use the `open_file` method of [`sublime.Window`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window)

e.g.,

```
sublime.active_window().open_file(path + '/style.css')
```

Although it would be best to ensure that it is explicitly closed in Python code before telling Sublime to open it.

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "focus the sidebar," but perhaps the [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) project is of some help as a model?

Comment: fantastic thank you, iv been trying .open_file(path + '/style.css') but didn't realise I needed the sublime.active_window() beforehand.

As for focusing the sidebar, I would like the assets folder that is created to be opened in the sidebar (as if user was to navigate to folder themselves in the filetree.

could it be something like sublime.active_window().run_command("reveal_in_side_bar")

Comment: Or if possible run a hotkey combination on the open style.css file (alt + shit +n) which would reveal in sidebar

Comment: @James: Hopefully someone knows, unfortunately, I don't. There is a `prompt_add_folder` command and a `remove_folder` command but nothing that adds a folder that I can find.

Comment: os.mkdir(path) creates the folder, I am trying to reveal this folder in sidebar to easily ftp the contents

Comment: thank you for the open file though, at least for the moment I can use a shortcut key to reveal on the style.css